# MS Test unit testing raised event contents

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, events, moq, mstest

I'm using **Microsoft's Visual Studio Test Tools** and **Moq** for unit testing.  I have a method that raises an event and I need to verify that the event's message is correct.

For example, the method calls this line of code:

```
_myEventPublisher.RaiseEvent(new MyEvent(message: myMessage))
```

And I need to verify the content of myMessage is correct.

I can successfully verify that the event is raised, with this line of code in the unit test:

```
For<IMyEventPublisher>()
                .Verify(x => x.RaiseEvent(It.IsAny<IMyEvent>()), Times.Exactly(1));
```

But I can't figure out how to verify the IMyEvent.Message string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
It.Is<IMyEvent>(m => Message == expected)
```

instead of

```
It.IsAny<IMyEvent>()
```

Comment: Thanks Serg!  I also had to add a setup: For<IMyEventPublisher>()
                    .Setup(mock => mock.RaiseEvent(It.IsAny<IMyEvent>()))
                    .Verifiable();